# Make every object in an Amazon S3 bucket publicly accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket on AWS to which I am uploading images from the frontend.

After successfully uploading an image to S3, this is the URL I get -

https://cewa-foundation-2020.s3.amazonaws.com/image8_%281%29.webp-1628768330444.webp

I want to make this URL public so that anyone with this link can view the image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: Are you asking how to do this for just that one file, or also for future files uploaded to the bucket? Or, would you like _all_ content in the bucket (or a specific path in the bucket) to be automatically public?

Comment: I want every object uploaded to that bucket to be public automatically. @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To make every object public you should add a **Bucket Policy** to the bucket.

- Go to the bucket's **Permissions** tab
- Go to the **Block public access** options
- **Turn off** the two options that mention **Bucket Policies**:

[image: S3 Block Public Access]

- Below that, **add a Bucket Policy** that grants access to anonymous users:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "PublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

All objects in the bucket **can now be accessed by anyone on the Internet**. However, they will not be able to *list* the contents of the bucket, so they will need to know the exact name of the object they want to access.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an object public by doing these below steps:

- Open the object by choosing the link on the object name.
- Choose the Permissions tab.
- Choose Edit.
- In the Everyone section, select Objects Read.
- Select I understand the effects of these changes on this object.
- Choose Save changes.

This is just one of the ways of doing it. Check the below link for more such ways.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/